# React JS Select clearable value not fully clearing out the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a ReactJS input control (example: https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/), which reads data from an API (JSON); What am noticing is that when the "x" is clicked, it will only clear  values that do not exist in the API and values that are partially typed. for example if value-1 exist as one of the objects in the API and "valu" is typed, the value will clear upon clicking the "x", but if I fully type "value-1", and click the "X", the value does not clear. So I added the clearable="true" to the select-input value and set it to true, but the value still fails to clear when the "X' is clicked

...here is the front-end code:

```
<Select
    name="client-dropdown"
    clearable="true"
    value={this.state.selected}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    options={this.state.clients.map(item => {
        item.value = item.clientid;
        item.label  = item.clientName;
        return item;
    })}
/>
```

**onchange method**:

```
onChange(e) {
    if(!e) return;

    const id = e.clientid;
    this.setState({ selected: id })

    const client = this.state.clients.find(x => x.clientid === id);
    this.props.onSelect(client)
  }
```

...could I get some help with this please?

Comment: Which version of react-select are you using?

Comment: I'm using the following version: react-select": "^1.2.1",

Comment: Would you post code for `this.onChange`?

Comment: I could not reproduce it on the [official sample](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/), but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/v1.2.1/examples/src/components/States.js) : it could either be your `this.onChange` code not unsetting the `this.state.selected` field or that there is a weird bug with clearable having string `true` instead of `true`

Comment: on an unrelated note, I remember author of react-select recommending to upgrade to 2.0 as it has lot of stability and improvements.

Comment: @Sung kim, sure, please see the edit in my original post, thank you